# Alamofire 4.0 - Set request content type

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire 4.4.0. 
I need to send POST request with params in url string (as in GET request) and with content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

My code is following:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON
```

Issue is that content type is always "application/json"
I also tried to set encoding to URLEncoding.queryString or .httpBody, also tried to set headers for request as **headers: ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]**

Please give some advice, how to set request content type in Alamofire 4.0

Comment: Read this-: https://grokswift.com/alamofire-custom-headers/

Comment: did you got solution?